# How to identify different records from two columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some simple records below in Excel spreadsheet. I did a True/False value in check column (very simple check) for small set of records.

```
  ID table 1    ID table 2  check
180065220   180065220   TRUE
180296833   180296833   TRUE
181457872   181457874   FALSE
181917974   181917974   TRUE
180296568   180593133   FALSE
181279364               FALSE
```

Here, I re-ordered the ID columns from table 1 and table 2 to identify the different records from these two tables and moved the differences to the bottom. Again, it's in Excel spreadsheet.

```
ID table 1  ID table 2  check
180065220   180065220   TRUE
180296833   180296833   TRUE
181917974   181917974   TRUE
181457872   181457874   FALSE
180296568   180593133   FALSE
181279364               FALSE
```

Is there a method/function that can allow me to identify the differences from records from table 1 and table 2 and place them at the bottom? It would not be feasible to manually using my current method for a large tables.

Comment: Joe, how large is your dataset and what formula are you using for `check` column? I'd think that you'd be able to sort your dataset and achieve desired results by simply sorting on `check` column.

Comment: @Justyna, any from 200k to 500k records in Excel.

Comment: I am using a true/false. if cell 2A = 2B then true else false.

Comment: Thanks - I'll upload my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help - you can use the following formula in column C:

```
=COUNTIF(B2,$A$2:$A$50000)
```

[image]

It literally takes a few seconds to get calculated for the whole dataset of 50k rows. Then you need to sort your dataset by column C - `Sort Largest to Smallest`:

[image]

It will keep the "common" IDs `1` at the top and push the differences `0` to the bottom. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works as expected for the same set of records i have posted. Thank you!